# Handling Low Memory in react Native

Tags: react-native

Is possible to do something like...

```
didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
  alert('You are doomed')
}
```

in react native ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's missing from the doc's (I couldn't find it but definitely remember seeing it at one time) but it's in the [TypeScript def's](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L6905)

```
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

AppState.addEventListener('memoryWarning', (state) => {

});
```

Should work.

Comment: thanks..but there is something wrong with the sintax...can you fix that ?

Comment: @MarcoJr What's the error? How are you importing ```React Native```?