# How to handle memory warnings in React Native iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

**Background:** I'm implementing a native iOS map component in Swift to be used in my React Native app. It lazy loads tiles onto the map as the user zooms / pans around, which causes the memory usage to gradually increase.

**Problem:** Occasionally, the memory usage gets too high and I need to clear the tile cache to bring it back down. In iOS, I understand that you can implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in the `UIViewController` to release some memory, but native iOS components for React Native don't have a `UIViewController`, only a `UIView`.

**Tried:** I've tried listening for memory warnings at the React Native level (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307692/1211080)), and then calling a native method exposed by `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` to free up some memory. However, I'd rather the native component take care of itself in terms of cleaning up memory.

**TL;DR:** How do I handle memory warnings at the iOS level for a React Native "native iOS" component?

Comment: Would you provide more details on *loads tiles onto the map*, maybe with code, of which component owns/manages these tiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I'd rather the native component take care of itself in terms
>   of cleaning up memory.

If you hold and manage tiles in native subclass of `UIViewController` (eg. `TileViewController`), then the simplest way is to do cleanup like in the following

```
class TileViewController: UIViewController {

    // this called automatically on system memory warning
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { 
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // clean up cached tiles here
    }
}
```